# AWS Glue crawler cannot recognize consistent CSV schema over historical files

Tags: aws-glue

We have a folder of .csv and .ctl files. The CSVs are daily files, five in total per day, over a period of time. Their naming convention is a prefixed string followed by a date identifier (Eg: ABCDE090619.csv). The header row, for each of the five daily files, is consistent over time.

The expected behaviour of the Glue crawler is to recognize the five table schemas and create a row for day's data within each table. Instead, the crawler creates an individual schema for every single file. Roughly 550 in total.

Is there any mechanism which that could be driving this behaviour? Our considerations currently include the naming convention but according to the Glue docs, only the file schema should matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Create a single schema for each S3 path" option for your crawler might help you. In the Console it's in the Output section of the crawler config under "Grouping behavior for S3 data."

Update: When using the option explained above, you must have files with different schemas separated into different folders. You can point the crawler at the root folder, but the folder structure tells it which files to group together.

Comment: Thanks - I did try hat originally but unfortunately no luck! Can you think of anything else it could be?

Comment: You could try having a separate folder for each type of table. I think you could still use one crawler, but the folder structure would theoretically tell it to group together those particular tables. I haven't tested that though.

Comment: Can you update your answer. Ill mark it as correct. I tried this about a week ago and forgot to update this question. Turns out that if theres different schemas in a single folder it can't group the files together correctly and results on creating a unique table (several thousand in my case.) Live and learn!